# iOS Safari Is Breaking a Centered Nested Div Randomly -- Is This a Webkit Issue?

Tags: css, safari

I am using the swiper.js as an infinite carousel used for an image select. One image on each page. When you select an image, it dims, and a checkmark appears.

This works perfect on every browser but iOS 10 webkit. It also gets broken even more in iOS Chrome which is an older version of Safari. To make matters worse, the MacOS Safari developer tools give me a completely different result. I'm totally lost here.

What could be causing the checkmark not to center responsively in Safari?

[Not on Safari -- Everything Works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCLzI.png)

[Safari -- The checkmark moves around the screen when scaled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zdVy.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-slide">         
              <div>
                <img class="imageselection" src="img/1.jpg">  
              </div>

              <div class="checkmark">
                <img src="img/checkmark.png">
              </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkmark {

      visibility: hidden!important;
      position: absolute!important;

    }

.checkmark.checkmarkon {

      visibility: visible!important;
      position: absolute!important;
      transition: .03s ease!important;
      opacity: 1;

    }

.imageselection {

      position: relative !important;
      margin-top: 0%!important;

    }

img.imageselection.opacity {

      opacity: 0.3;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, everyone who downvoted me can DIAGF. You are all dicks.

Secondly, WebKit is backwards. My problem stemmed from poor Apple documentation, and a lack of general WebKit information. It would be great to ignore it, but if you want something to work on iOS you should probably start there as other engines adapt better than the other way around.

Finally, the answer was found here: https://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Someone who definitely is a good human, with a soul.

The relevant code change was this:

```
.checkmark  {
visibility: hidden!important;
position: absolute!important;
margin: auto !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: auto;
height: auto%;
display: -webkit-box !important;
display: -ms-flexbox!important;
display: -webkit-flex !important;
display: flex !important;
-webkit-box-pack: center !important;
-ms-flex-pack: center !important;
-webkit-justify-content: center !important;
justify-content: center !important;
-webkit-box-align: center !important;
-ms-flex-align: center !important;
-webkit-align-items: center!important;
align-items: center!important;

}
```

You hopefully can ignore the !importants  :-). I'm too lazy to edit the core css of the swiper.js and onsenui framework.